# SSRS auto display data in another page when save as PDF

Tags: pdf, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have a nested group property `Member` and `Date` where `Date` is nested in `Member`. My data has returned me 3 Date which resulted in 3 Group.

First group have 2 records and second group have 3 records while third group having 10 records.

Problem here is first 2 group displayed in first page while third group automatically display in second page eventhou first page still have plenty of spaces. 
May I how to configure so that half of the third group will display in first page while the other half display in second page?

Comment: There is a General Property of the Row Group: "Keep together on one page if possible", you'll have to set this to false.

Comment: @NickyvV: May I know where is the setting?

Comment: @NickyvV: I don't see such option under Row Group

Comment: Oh sorry, it's in the Tablix properties

Comment: @NickyvV: I've found the setting but it was false..so i guess the problem is not that..

Comment: Does this also happen when the report is rendered in the Report Manager? Or only in PDF? It could be a margins/page width/body width issue.

Comment: @NickyvV : Most common solution on this site is to check the width problem and I've already checked that. The problem was happened at the `print layout` as well as the pdf file